# How can I configure ~/.ssh/config such that `ssh foo.bar` results in a connection to `foo.internal.bar`?

Tags: ssh, configuration, openssh

I have a system with both a public (e.g server1.**foo.bar**) and privately-resolvable (e.g. server1.**internal.foo.bar**) DNS name. SSH connections are only possible via the private IP, but I always think of these hosts in terms of their public name.

I would like to:

- connect to the right IP regardless of whether I remember to use the `*.internal.bar` pattern
- save keystrokes

I'm aware of the [substitution tokens](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh_config#TOKENS) such as `%h` that can be used to modify the hostname given at the commandline, e.g.

```
Host foo
    Hostname %h.some.other.domain
```

The behavior I'm looking for would be something like:

```
Host *.foo.bar
    Hostname %m.internal.foo.bar
```

Where `%m` gets substituted with just the portion of the given hostname **up to the first dot**. I've read `man 5 ssh_config` as well as https://man.openbsd.org/ssh_config and couldn't find the answer, if one even exists. I'm using macOS 10.15.4:

```
$ ssh -V
OpenSSH_8.1p1, LibreSSL 2.7.3
```

Comment: Why don't you add `server1.foo.bar` to your `/etc/hosts` with the address of `server1.internal.foo.bar`? Then the name will also work outside of ssh (ping, http, git...).

Comment: @xenoid because then I could not properly test anything else running on that server, this is specifically for SSH connections, not HTTP etc.

Comment: The `Hostname` thing in the SHH config works for single hosts, so I assume you have many servers? This is something I would solve with a small script or a loop that generates aliases. Or you just define 'serverX` in your `/etc/hosts` and use `ssh serverX`. On my Linux I get bash command completion of `ssh` with host names that are in `/etc/hosts` so in practice you would just enter the ends of the names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a working method. It's a bit ugly, but it does work. This leverages the `ProxyCommand` directive (see [manpage](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh_config#ProxyCommand)) combined with a small bash helper script.

1. Add sections like this to **~/.ssh/config** — one for each domain you want remapped:

```
Match final host="!*.corp.foo.com,*.foo.com"
    ProxyCommand ssh_ext2int %h %p

Match final host="*.quux.biz"
    ProxyCommand ssh_ext2int %h %p
```

2. Save this in your `$PATH` somewhere as **ssh_ext2int** — and `chmod u+x` it:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

[ $# -eq 2 ] || exit 1
typeset -A dmap
dmap=(
  [foo.com]=corp.foo.com
  [quux.biz]=internal.qux.lan
)

d=${1#*.}
h=${1%%.*}
nd=${dmap[$d]:-$d}

/usr/bin/nc -w 120 $h.$nd $2 2>/dev/null
```

Now, `ssh server158247.quux.biz` should connect you to `server158247.internal.qux.lan`

Answer (score 0):

This particular thing you ask for is not possible with OpenSSH. These constructs are really meant only for simple aliases and not for complex replacements such as you ask. If these servers have some specific format, you can make them aliases (without the domain name):

```
Host server*
    Hostname %h.internal.foo.bar
```

If you need some more complex matches for the aliases (lets say you have a file containing all your hosts. This can be either manually created or automatically updated from DNS), you can use something like this

```
Match exec "grep %h %d/.ssh/internal_hosts"
    Hostname %h.internal.foo.bar
```

The last resort is to generate the ssh_config from the above list/DNS, which will have the whole hardcoded items for all your hosts. It does not have to be the main configuration file, but just some included one. The configuration files are really just a text files.

Comment: But... the `%m` token does not exist! I made it up to illustrate the behavior I was seeking. So, the examples you posted don't work.

Comment: Well ... obviously I meant the `%h`. Fixed now.